# my google maps API is effected by the internet provider

Tags: api, location, maps

I have used a valid google maps API on my site. But it gives the wrong location when the user clicks on the "current location" button, it appears that the problem is from the internet provider.

As the support team say:

> The current location is get through the IP. Sometimes the internet provider changes the IP for some services. And for this reason, it gives the wrong one.

Is there any way to solve this?